# Setting cells in a table not in the same height

Tags: html, css

how do i set cells in the same row (`td` in a `tr`) to not be in the same height?

i have tried using "height" attribute for the td and it didnt work.

here is an example of a table:http://jsfiddle.net/pMUY3/27/ I want the second td(the one with the border) to be set as the size of the hhh line only

Tnx for the help :D

Comment: To ***not*** be in the same height? Table cells will always match to the [largest content in a row](http://jsfiddle.net/rc9Rh/).

Comment: i want it to not be, there is no way?

Comment: Nope, that I know of! you'll be wanting to use `<div>`s if you need mismatching content sizes or maybe nested tables (Which I think won't work) etc

Answer (score 0):

The `height` attribute of `<td>` is deprecated in HTML 4.01.

add style to `td` element `style="height: 10px;"` e.g.

Comment: the `height` is set, and it apply to second td, but the point is that, in a row, all `td` element get maximum height of largest td, you can set `textalign` css for other `td` to arrange them

Comment: ahh got my answer tnx